# Generating HTML from markdown only works with dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-dom

I am trying to write a simple markdwon previewer.
the problem is when I insert the Generated HTML text inside a div in render method like this:

```js
render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {this.state.genHTML}
     </div>  
  );
}
```

it does not rendered, and displays as it written with its tags just like as if a string.
**But** with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` the Generated HTML is got rendered.

**I want to know why this occurs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, setting HTML from code is risky(because of cross-site scripting (XSS)), and this is why in React you need to use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" to set it. This is just a rule that you need to follow if you want to use a React framework.